# JavaScript order of operations

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve info from an object but I can't seem to get it in the correct order. Doing it this way, `total` is always equal to `null`.

How do I ensure ensure that the `total` is always filled before calculating the average?

you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5pLppq2t/1/) that y remains undefined

```
$(function () {
    var data =[];
    var time =[];
    var abc =[
        {"val":"2015-07-02 03:55:00","name":"TIME_STAMP"},
        {"val":"19981","name":"TOTAL"},
        {"val":"2051","name":"\"A\""},
        {"val":"274","name":"\"B\""},
        {"val":"8826","name":"\"C\""},
        {"val":"5351","name":"\"D\""},
        {"val":"2628","name":"\"E\""},
        {"val":"501","name":"\"F\""},
        {"val":"350","name":"\"G\""},
        {"val":" ","name":"\"H\" "}];
    var total = null;

    $.each(abc,function(i,el){
        if (el.name == "TIME_STAMP") {
            time.push({ name: el.name, y: parseInt(el.val) });
        }
        else if (el.name == "TOTAL") {
            total = parseInt(el.val);
        }
        else if (total != null) {
            var p = parseFloat(el.val) / total * 100;
            data.push({name: el.name, y: p});
            console.log(el.name + " " + el.y);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: @Teemu var abc, it's an example of what it's actually doing

Comment: How is the JSON loaded? Your code works in its current state.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe: http://jsbin.com/maqemuletu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Archer obviously, I'll remove the tag and maybe we can get to the point

Comment: [Me neither](http://jsfiddle.net/5pLppq2t/)

Comment: Shouldn't `else if (total != null)` be `if (total != null)`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5pLppq2t/1/

Comment: @PT_C - It should be `console.log(el.name + " " + p);`  There is no `el.y` ... http://jsfiddle.net/5pLppq2t/2/

Comment: @RobertOliveira no because I don't want the total part of the data object

Answer (score 0):

Change this line...

```
console.log(el.name + " " + el.y);
```

to this...

```
console.log(el.name + " " + p);
```

There is no `el.y`.

Alternatively, create `el.y` instead of `p`...

```
$.each(abc,function(i,el){
    if (el.name == "TIME_STAMP") {
        time.push({ name: el.name, y: parseInt(el.val) });
    }
    else if (el.name == "TOTAL") {
        total = parseInt(el.val);
    }
    else if (total != null) {
        el.y = parseFloat(el.val) / total * 100;
        data.push({name: el.name, y: el.y});
        console.log(el.name + " " + el.y);
    }
});
```

Comment: why is p not getting pushed to y?

Comment: It is, but within your data object. So `data[i].y` should work (i = index)

Comment: There you go - I've added a bit extra that makes it populate `el.y`.  What you were previously doing was creating a new object with `name` and `y` properties, assigning values to those properties, and then pushing that new object into the array `data`.  At no point were you actually assigning the value `p` to anything else, so `el.y` never actually existed.  The above code I added will now add a property `y` to each of the objects in `abc`, assigning the percentage value to each of them, as well as populating `data` with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this check fixed it.

```
$.each(json, function(i,el){
        if (el.val != " "){
            if(el.name == "TIME_STAMP" || el.name == "TOTAL"){
                excess.push({name: el.name, y: parseInt(el.val)});
            }else{
                endData.push({name: el.name, y: parseInt(el.val)});
            }
        }
    });
```